# Error matplotlib.lines.Line2D en matplotlib.pyplot

Tags: python, matplotlib

Estoy trabajando desde la terminal Linux de Fedora 32 y cuando intento graficar me da como error `[<matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0x7efe71e19280>]`
Al trabajar desde spyder no tengo ningún problema, pero prefiero la terminal, les escribo un código de prueba.

```
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>>> a=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
>>> b=a
>>> plt.plot(a,b)
[<matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0x7efe71e19280>]
>>> plt.show
<function show at 0x7efe76b523a0>
```

Con este código me da estos problemas y no puedo graficar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No es un error. Generó la gráfica pero estás usando `plt.show` en vez de [`plt.show()`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.show.html#matplotlib.pyplot.show) para invocar el método correctamente y mostrar la ventana correspondiente.

```
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>>> a=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
>>> b=a
>>> plt.plot(a,b)
[<matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0x7efe71e19280>]
>>> plt.show()
```

Comment: Ya lo revisé, gracias.

Comment: @JasmirAguilera te resolvió el problema? Sigue sin mostrar la gráfica? Si resolvió tu pregunta, puedes marcar la respuesta como aceptada con el tick verde a la izquierda de la respuesta, bajo los votos. Si no, siéntete libre de editar tu pregunta e indicar qué más falla :)